# Parsing a List of Arbitrary Size into an XML-like String

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6, stack, logic

I have an array that is arranged in the following:

```
let example_arr = 
    [
        "backend",
        [
            "#host#www.example.com",
            "#port#80"
        ],
        "endpoints",
        [
            "endpoint",
            [
                "#external#/foo/bar/cat/mom/",
                "#internal#/banana/",
                "params",
                [
                    "param",
                    [
                        "#sourceValue#acis.usermove.md"
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ];
```

This array needs to be parsed into a string that would look like this:

```
"
<backend host="www.example.com" port="80" />
<endpoints>
    <endpoint external="/foo/bar/cat/mom/" internal="/banana/"/>
        <params>
            <param sourceValue="acis.usermove.md" />
        </params>
    </endpoint>
</endpoints>
"
```

I have been working at this problem for awhile, but have scrapped attempt after attempt. Here is my latest try:

```
let str_answer = helper_string_builder(example_arr, 3);

function helper_string_builder(xml_list_data, depth) {
    let string_builder = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < xml_list_data.length; i++) {
        if (Array.isArray(xml_list_data[i]) !== true) {
            if (xml_list_data[i].charAt(0) !== "#" && xml_list_data[i].length > 1) {

                if(typeof xml_list_data[i + 1] === "undefined"){
                    continue;
                }

                string_builder += " ".repeat(depth) + "<" + xml_list_data[i] + ">\n";

                for (let j = 0; j < xml_list_data[i + 1].length; j++) {
                    if (j === 0) {
                        string_builder += " ".repeat(depth + 3)
                    }
                    string_builder +=
                        value_reader("name", xml_list_data[i + 1][j]) +
                        "=\"" +
                        value_reader("content", xml_list_data[i + 1][j]) +
                        "\" ";
                }

                string_builder += "\n" + " ".repeat(depth) + "</" + xml_list_data[i] + ">\n";

            }
            console.log(string_builder);
        } else {
            string_builder += helper_string_builder(xml_list_data[i], depth + 3);
        }
    }
    return string_builder;
}


function value_reader(mode, str) {
    str = str + '';
    if (str.substring(0, 1) != '#') {
        return 'ERROR';
    }
    if (mode === "name") {
        let start_pos = str.indexOf('#') + 1;
        let end_pos = str.indexOf('#', start_pos);
        let name_cutout = str.substring(start_pos, end_pos);
        return name_cutout;
    } else if (mode === "content") {
        let start_pos = str.indexOf('#') + 1;
        let end_pos = str.indexOf('#', start_pos);
        let content_cutout = str.substring(end_pos + 1);
        return content_cutout;
    } else {
        throw new Error("Valid \'mode\' not passed in");
    }
}
```

Unsure how to continue with solving this, I was wondering if anyone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input format is quite tricky, so I guess my main advice is to go trough the tree twice:

1. First, create an easier-to-work-with tree of `Element` objects: each object has a `tagName` property, an `attributes` array, and a `children` array.

   - The `attributes` array *can* contain `Attribute` instances, which are `{ key, value }` pairs
   - The `children` array *can* contain `Element` instances.
2. Then, loop over your tree and return strings for each `Element`

### Reformating the data

The code got a bit messy, but I (think I) reused most of your logic:

- If it's a string and starts with `"#"`, it's an attribute
- If it's a string and not an attribute, it's a new `Element`
- If it's an array, the array contains the contents of the previously made `Element`

```js
// Recursively create a tree of elements with attributes and children
const partition = xs => xs.reduce(
  ([lastPart, ...parts], x) => {
    switch(getType(x)) {
      case Element:
        return [
          Element(x), 
          ...(lastPart ? [lastPart] : []),
          ...parts
        ];
      case Array:
        const attrsUntil = x.findIndex(Attribute.isNoAttribute);
        
        const attrs = attrsUntil !== -1 
          ? x.slice(0, attrsUntil)
          : x;
          
        const children = attrsUntil === -1
          ? []
          : x.slice(attrsUntil);
          
        return [ Element(
          lastPart.tagName,
          attrs.map(Attribute.fromString),
          partition(children)
        ), ...parts];
      default:
        return [ lastPart, ...parts ];        
    }
  },
  []
).reverse()

const getType = x => 
  Array.isArray(x) ? Array
  : Attribute.isAttribute(x) ? Attribute
  : Element;
  
// Some utility models & methods:
const Attribute = (key, value) =>
  ({ key, value });
  
Attribute.isAttribute = (str) =>
  str.charAt && str.charAt(0) === "#";

Attribute.isNoAttribute = x => !Attribute.isAttribute(x);

Attribute.fromString = str => Attribute(
  ...str.split("#").slice(1)
);

const Element = (tagName, attributes = [], children = []) => 
  ({ tagName, attributes, children });
  
  

let example_arr = 
    [
        "backend",
        [
            "#host#www.example.com",
            "#port#80"
        ],
        "endpoints",
        [
            "endpoint",
            [
                "#external#/foo/bar/cat/mom/",
                "#internal#/banana/",
                "params",
                [
                    "param",
                    [
                        "#sourceValue#acis.usermove.md"
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ];
    
console.log(
  partition(example_arr)
);
```

### From tree to string

With the new format, the string formatting can be implemented separately like so:

```js
// The formatted tree:
const input = [{tagName:"backend",attributes:[{key:"host",value:"www.example.com"},{key:"port",value:"80"}],children:[]},{tagName:"endpoints",attributes:[],children:[{tagName:"endpoint",attributes:[{key:"external",value:"/foo/bar/cat/mom/"},{key:"internal",value:"/banana/"}],children:[{tagName:"params",attributes:[],children:[{tagName:"param",attributes:[{key:"sourceValue",value:"acis.usermove.md"}],children:[]}]}]}]}];

// A helper to prefix with an indentation
const indented = (n, str) => `${" ".repeat(n)}${str}`;

// This renders a self closing tag
const renderEmptyEl = (el, indent) => indented(
  indent,
  `<${el.tagName} ${renderAttributes(el)} />`
);

// This renders a tag that has children
const renderParentEl = (el, indent) => [
  indented(indent, `<${el.tagName} ${renderAttributes(el)}>`),
  ...el.children.map(c => renderEl(c, indent + 2)),
  indented(indent, `</${el.tagName}>`)
].join("\n");

const renderEl = (el, indent) => el.children.length
  ? renderParentEl(el, indent) : renderEmptyEl(el, indent);

// Render the attribute values
const renderAttributes = ({ attributes }) => attributes
  .map(({ key, value }) => `${key}="${value}"`)
  .join(" ");

// Entry point for an array of nodes not inside another Element
const renderTree = (nodes) => 
  nodes.map(n => renderEl(n, 0)).join("\n");

console.log(renderTree(input));
```

Comment: My goodness... this is amazing. I have been banging my head against this forever and the implementation I came up with still derived obscure errors. Swapping my logic with yours, the code immediately became traceable and the output consistent. Hats off to you, user3297291!